# POST form with jQuery and handle the result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Is it possible to POST a form through jQuery and also handle the result? (without using json, ajax etc).

Something like this:

```
<form id="loginform">
      //some input fields and a submit button.
</form>
```

and then from jQuery:

```
$("#loginform").submit(function (e) {
   $.post("somePHPscript")
   .done(function (response) {  
        //Handle response
});
});
```

.. or would that equal removing the form, and just binding an event to the submit-button, and take the inputs manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why you would want a form that handles the submission result by overriding the default form action and not using ajax etc.

You will want to read this: http://api.jquery.com/submit/ which will outline how to capture the form submission event, you can prevent the move to another page by using the `event.preventDefault()` as outlined in the above link.

Comment: Yes, and in the link they also use the input field manually with:  if ( $( "input:first" ).val() === "correct" ) - so my question was whether it could be done all-together, or if i had to pull the information from the inputs manually. :-) Remember i need this done with a POST-request.

Comment: Why does it need to be in a form doing a post request if you don't want the form to perform any kind of submission?

In the use case you are outlining, you are going to have to pull out the data from the inputs and operate on them, unless you can pull the data out of the event parameter.

Comment: By manually using the inputs, i meant perform the $.post only from within jQuery, something like: $.post( "somePHPscript.php", {un: $("#usernameinput").val, pw: $("#passwordinput").val}); - check out betomoretti's answer.. I don't know if it works, but it's toward what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have will handle the response. You just have to do something with it. If you're returning a string of text, you can do something like this:

```
.done(function(response){
  alert(response);
});
```

If you are returning some HTML, maybe something like this:

```
.done(function(response){
  $(response).insertAfter('div');
});
```

**EDIT**

Of course, if you submit the form, then there is no point in trying to retrieve a response from the server. But right now your code is submitting the form and trying to do an AJAX request. Might as well stop the form from submitting and doing the AJAX request so you can do something with the response.

Comment: Well, basically i want the form submitted no matter what (from the form action or jQuery submit-click-event), but i want the response to end up in the jQuery so i can handle the result.

Comment: If you submit the form, you will be taken to a different page or the page will refresh. All you need to do is send the data to the server and handle the response. So onClick, you make an AJAX call to the server and the response will be delivered back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="the-form" role="form"> 
  <input type="button" id="button-form">
</form>

$("#button-form").on('click', function (e) {    
   e.preventDefault();
   $.post($("#the-form").attr('action'), function(response) {console.log(response)});
});
```

Comment: Did you test it? When i run it, it seems to print all my HTML on my page.. But your response is somewhat what i hoped to find - if only it will work..

Comment: if the url that you call returns a string, the response is gonna be a string... if it returns a whole html page... it is gonna be the whole page.. the url should return just what you need to process.. a data, a string, a div...  http://jsfiddle.net/rd7yne9m/ look at the console to see the result